# Can a 10 kΩ potentiometer replace a 50 kΩ potentiometer on a volume control board?

Tags: amplifier, potentiometer

I have an Onkyo A-9010 amplifier, which has a faulty potentiometer on the volume control board.

[image: Volume control board]

[Service Manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwirypDX2vr5AhVSiv0HHabQB1YQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vintageshifi.com%2Frepertoire-pdf%2Fpdf%2Ftelecharge.php%3Fpdf%3DOnkyo-A-9010-Service-Manual.pdf&usg=AOvVaw17_0vGtekkYVgXXhhWOFqZ)

It's a 50 kΩ, linear (not sure) stereo, motor-driven potentiometer. In Hungary, where I live, I only have access to an ALPS 10 kΩ, D-log, stereo, motor-driven potentiometer, or a 100 kΩ one, but not 47 kΩ or 50 kΩ.

What happens if I change it to 10 kΩ or 100 kΩ instead of 50 kΩ?

If it matters, I never use the loudness button or bass and treble knobs; the direct button is always on.
Can this potentiometer be replaced with a digital potentiometer?

Comment: The pot in question has a fixed tap on it. Is the replacement pot the same?

Comment: The same design, same size, except the resistance.

Comment: How is the pot faulty? Have you checked the solder joints, cleaned it, and measured if it outputs the volume control voltage properly? Because it might be that the problem is elsewhere. This pot just outputs a linear (B) control voltage, which is sampled by a microcontroller with ADC. Changing the pot curve may be a problem, actual resistance is likely less of an issue.

Comment: I checked the board and it looked good, no crack, or anything like that. I resoldered the potentiometer legs. At the moment, relatively loud music can be heard at zero volume position, if i push the tap or do "knock-knock" on it, the volume is lowering or increasing. I measured the resistance when i did the resoldering, it was 45-46 kΩ at zero position, but at that time when i put it back in the amplifier, it was good for 3-4 days, and after a few cycle of volume changing got worse, right now i can hear music at zero. I didnt make any more measures, becuase i dont understand how it works.

Comment: If the pot is broken the volume should go down, not up. And only one half of the pot is used so you don't need a replacement as you can switch to the currently unused half of the pot assembly. Likely the problem is elsewhere like connectors between boards having bad connections.

Comment: This board is separated from the others, and i have pushed everything, and didnt cause any volume change, except this. This potentiometer is attached to the front with two screws by the potentiometer's house/case, and the only thing i can move this way is the potentimeter itself by the tap. The volume is already high, if i push it or something it goes down, back to normal, then goes back to same high volume. I saw these symptoms (exactly the same with other people), and the solution was replacing the pot every time, my question is,can i replace it with a 10kΩ one? What you think?

Comment: @Justme Whether the volume goes up or down would depend on which leg  of the pot is broken. The volume is controlled with a voltage between 0 and ~3.3V, break one end contact and the voltage goes to whatever the remaining contact's voltage is. I've seen quite a few wired like this where the ground pin opens and it's stuck at full volume. Agree on trying the unused pot, unlikely both would be bad.

Comment: It looks like the pot is just generating a 0 to 3.3V control voltage for an ADC. In that case 10K should be just fine. You'd want to keep the taper the same if possible.

Comment: Well, i f*ed up the board. During soldering i ripped off some of the conductive layer, so the pcb is probably garbage. Is it possible to bypass this piece with something? Is there any external board for this purpose? :(